# How to add fading transition on a changing image?

Tags: html, jquery, css, web, jss

I have this code:

HTML

```
<div id='features-buttons'>
   <button class='features-button' id='theButton' onclick='featureImage1()' type='button'><i class='fa fa-briefcase'/> Home Office</button>
   <button class='features-button' id='theButton' onclick='featureImage2()' type='button'><i class='fa fa-plus-circle'/> The Mezzaine (Add On)</button>
</div>

<img class='features-image' id='theImage' src='https://media.designcafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/17054904/interior-designer-or-decorator-make-your-choice-1.jpg' style='border-radius:30px;'/>
```

CSS

```
.features-image{
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.features-button{
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-family: 'Jost';
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fff;
    color: #453011;
    margin: 5px 25%;
}
```

JS

```
function featureImage1(){
    document.getElementById(&quot;theImage&quot;).src=&quot;https://media.designcafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/17054904/interior-designer-or-decorator-make-your-choice-1.jpg&quot;;
}

function featureImage2(){
    document.getElementById(&quot;theImage&quot;).src=&quot;https://hommes.studio/wp-content/uploads/Get-To-Know-Interior-Design-Trends-2022_16.jpg&quot;;
}
```

I have image changer code this is by replacing the source of the image, but I want to add transition when the image is changing.

Comment: As tagged [tag:jquery] despite not using any... don't change ".src" as it'll need an additional event to know when it's loaded - instead add both images as separate `<img>` tags then `$("#img1").fadeOut(() => $("#img2").fadeIn())`  you may want to animate opacity instead if that forces your page to "jump".   Depends on the images/layout.

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML or is it fixed? A small point, you should not have two elements with the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CSS` transitions. Here's your code updated, I added a transition property to the `.features-image` class with a duration of `0.5 seconds` and an easing function of `ease-in-out`. I also added two new classes: `.fade` and `.show`, which will control the `opacity` of the image during the transition.

In `JavaScript` code, I added the `.fade` class to the image before changing its `src` attribute. After a 500ms delay (the same duration as the transition), I change the `src` attribute and remove the `.fade` class. I then add the `.show` class to make the image fully visible again. This causes the fade transition to occur between the two images:

```js
function featureImage1(){
    var img = document.getElementById("theImage");
    img.classList.remove("show");
    img.classList.add("fade");
    setTimeout(function(){
        img.src="https://media.designcafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/17054904/interior-designer-or-decorator-make-your-choice-1.jpg";
        img.classList.remove("fade");
        img.classList.add("show");
    }, 500);
}

function featureImage2(){
    var img = document.getElementById("theImage");
    img.classList.remove("show");
    img.classList.add("fade");
    setTimeout(function(){
        img.src="https://hommes.studio/wp-content/uploads/Get-To-Know-Interior-Design-Trends-2022_16.jpg";
        img.classList.remove("fade");
        img.classList.add("show");
    }, 500);
}
```

```css
.features-image{
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    object-fit: cover;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.features-image.fade {
    opacity: 0;
}

.features-image.show {
    opacity: 1;
}

.features-button{
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-family: 'Jost';
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fff;
    color: #453011;
    margin: 5px 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id='features-buttons'>
   <button class='features-button' id='theButton' onclick='featureImage1()' type='button'><i class='fa fa-briefcase'/> Home Office</button>
   <button class='features-button' id='theButton' onclick='featureImage2()' type='button'><i class='fa fa-plus-circle'/> The Mezzaine (Add On)</button>
</div>

<img class='features-image' id='theImage' src='https://media.designcafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/17054904/interior-designer-or-decorator-make-your-choice-1.jpg' style='border-radius:30px;'/>
```